# sql like and between

Tags: sql, between, sql-like

Look at these two queries

```
SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE user_name BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z' 
ORDER  BY user_name

SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE user_name LIKE '[a-z]%'
```

Shouldn't they give the same answers?
The first one is returning answers 603 and second one is not returning anything

Comment: Could you provide a small amount of sample data please

Answer (score 2):

No, because the evil me can enter a username that starts with whitespace, or a username like Zina

That's not in the range A-Z ('Zina' for example would be in the range A-ZZ). 
You'd probably get the (more or less) same results if you'd use

```
WHERE user_name BETWEEN 'A' AND 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
```

Furthermore, it depends on the case-sensitivity of the collation.
The second query gets all usernames that start with a to z, but they may include other start characters, because there might just be some fancy turkish characters in that range ([for real](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/725949/case-sensitivity-doesnt-work-when-using-a-range-in-like-with-collate-latin1-general-cs-as)).

You'de be much better of using

```
WHERE user_name LIKE '[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%'
```

That's assuming you have ASCII-only usernames.
(That doesn't work for German äöü, for example)

**Note:**
Your last remark leads my to conclude your second query returns nothing.
You didn't indicate the RDBMS system type you use, but if you're using PostGreSQL, the reason why you get nothing in the second query is that postgre is case-sensitive, and in your between query, you use capital letters. I assume your usernames start with capital letters (Haha ;) )?

When PostGre and you want a case-insensitive query, use ILIKE:

```
WHERE user_name ILIKE '[a-z]%'
```

Comment: you are right but atleast 2nd query should too return vaules if first query is returning 600+ rows

Comment: @user2782906: Ah, are you using PostGre ? It's case sensitive. Use ILIKE instead of LIKE.

Answer (score 1):

First statement get all user_name greater / equal than A and lower / equal Z (applying alphabetical sort)

The second get all user_name start a-z.

If you have these rows:

Angel

Berthold

Samantha

Vanessa

Zuma

The first query gets:

Angel

Berthold

Samantha

Vanessa

The second gets... nothing

Comment: sir a-z is range .chk this link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_wildcard_charlist2&ss=-1

Comment: @user2782906: Hi, please add tag about your DBMS. On sqlfiddle about MySql doesn't work, in Sql Server yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mysql then like range wild cards([a-z]) will not work. try using 'RLIKE' instead. - where RLIKE '[a-z]'

between A to Z will do lexical ordered match where =>A and <=Z
example {A,AA,BA,CA,Z,ZA} with this condition will retrieve {A,AA,BA,CA,Z} and not ZA
but in [a-z]% you will get all rows including ZA.

Comment: m not getting even a single row in mysql in second query

Comment: in mysql wildcard range will not work for LIKE, try using RLIKE example: Select * from user where RLIKE '[a-z]';